# Dynamically dig into JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

Okay, so I need to dynamically dig into a JSON structure with PHP and I don't even know if it is possible.

So, let's say that my JSON is stored ad the variable `$data`:

```
$data = {
  'actions':{
     'bla': 'value_actionBla',
     'blo': 'value_actionBlo', 
  }
}
```

So, to access the value of `value_actionsBla`, I just do `$data['actions']['bla']`. Simple enough.

My JSON is dynamically generated, and the next time, it is like this:

```
$data = {
  'actions':{
     'bla': 'value_actionBla',
     'blo': 'value_actionBlo', 
     'bli':{
       'new': 'value_new'
     }
  }
}
```

Once again, to get the `new_value`, I do: `$data['actions']['bli']['new']`.

I guess you see the issue.

If I need to *dig* two levels, then I need to write `$data['first_level']['second_level']`, with three, it will be `$data['first_level']['second_level']['third_level']` and so on ...

Is there any way to perform such actions dynamically? (given I know the keys)

**EDIT_0:** Here is an example of how I do it so far (in a not dynamic way, with 2 *levels*)

```
// For example, assert that 'value_actionsBla' == $data['actions']['bla']
foreach($data as $expected => $value) {
  $this->assertEquals($expected, $data[$value[0]][$value[1]]);
}
```

**EDIT_1**

I have made a recursive function to do it, based on the solution of @Matei Mihai:

```
private function _isValueWhereItSupposedToBe($supposedPlace, $value, $data){
        foreach ($supposedPlace as $index => $item) {
            if(($data = $data[$item]) == $value)
                return true;
            if(is_array($item))
                $this->_isValueWhereItSupposedToBe($item, $value, $data);
        }
        return false;
}

public function testValue(){
        $searched = 'Found';
        $data = array(
            'actions'  => array(
                'abort' => '/abort',
                'next' => '/next'
            ),
            'form' => array(
                'title' => 'Found'
            )
        );
        $this->assertTrue($this->_isValueWhereItSupposedToBe(array('form', 'title'), $searched, $data));
}
```

Comment: Do you know in advance where the value you're looking for is going to be? Like, `actions` is an array of named actions, when is the value a string or an object?

Comment: In the 2 examples there are looking for different keys. How do you know what node you're looking for? You can use a recursive function in order to iterate over all the nodes but without a constant name to search it won't work.

Comment: I know everything in advance because it is a PHPUnit testsuite. For a specific request, I know that I should receive a specific JSON.

Comment: But if you know keys sequence - why don't you put them in array and then iterate that, de-referencing current part of the json?

Comment: @AlmaDo: Because it is too static that way. I will edit my question with an example.

Comment: @felipsmartins: Thanks for your precious help. Can you develop?

Comment: I meant stuff like `$value = $data; foreach($keys as $key) {$value = $value[$key]; } //now your $value contains your desired stuff`

Comment: @Mornor Not, I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```
function array_search_by_key_recursive($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $needle) {
             return $value;
        }
        if (is_array($value) && ($result = array_search_by_key_recursive($needle, $value)) !== false) {
             return $result;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$arr = ['test' => 'test', 'test1' => ['test2' => 'test2']];

var_dump(array_search_by_key_recursive('test2', $arr));
```

The result is `string(5) "test2"`

Comment: I have made some improvements based on your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this to traverse down an array recursively (given you know all the keys for the value you want to access!):

```php
function array_get_nested_value($data, array $keys) {
    if (empty($keys)) {
        return $data;
    }
    $current = array_shift($keys);
    if (!is_array($data) || !isset($data[$current])) {
        // key does not exist or $data does not contain an array
        // you could also throw an exception here
        return null;
    }
    return array_get_nested_value($data[$current], $keys);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$array = [
    'test1' => [
        'foo' => [
            'hello' => 123
        ]
    ],
    'test2' => 'bar'
];
array_get_nested_value($array, ['test1', 'foo', 'hello']); // will return 123
```